# Is there a corpus of "nice", inoffensive English words?

Tags: nlp, english, corpora

I'm looking for an English language corpus that doesn't include profanity or "unpleasant" words to generate easy to remember passwords and other strings for users. Does anybody know of such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Electronic Frontier Foundation actually publishes [wordlists](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/07/new-wordlists-random-passphrases) that fit my requirements. Among other criteria for the lists:

> We manually checked and attempted to remove as many profane,
> insulting, sensitive, or emotionally-charged words as possible, and
> also filtered based on several public lists of vulgar English words
> (for example this one published by Luis von Ahn).

Answer (score 1):

This [positive words text file](https://gist.github.com/mkulakowski2/4289437) posted by a user on GitHub. It contains 2000+ positive English's words.

Comment: Good start, but "misspelled words appear" in this list (it seems to be from social media) and 2000 is very short. There are at least ~750k words in English!

Comment: Perhaps it's very short because it embraces a particular notion about what constitutes an "unpleasant" word. Without a clear explanation of what you mean by "unpleasant", it's going to be hard for anyone to recommend a list. Take a word like "pulchritude". Would that be acceptable to you. To many people, it is one of the most horrible sounding words in English, but it is a synonym for "beauty"